# MySQL how to create a select subquery within this query

Tags: mysql, sql

How exactly would I be able to turn these two queries into one query by utilizing a subquery?

```
select p.id, m.display_name, m.updated_at, group_concat(meta.value) as value, p.path
from metadata_custom meta
right join page as p on p.id = meta.page_id
inner join metadata m on p.metadata_id = m.id
where p.path like '/history/%' and p.path not like '/history/%/%'
group by p.id

SELECT * FROM cascade_publish.folder
where path like '/history/%' and path not like '/history/%/%'
```

Most sub queries I have seen use WHERE IN....
Preferably I should be able to put the second query somewhere within the first query, how would I go about that?

Comment: It isn't clear how these two queries are related.

Answer (score 0):

One method is to use the subquery as a select field:

```
SELECT p.id
 ( SELECT folder FROM cascade_publish
   where path like '/history/%' and path not like '/history/%/%') as publish_folder
FROM ...
```

Comment: I have tried using that way with something like: select p.id, m.display_name, m.updated_at, group_concat(meta.value) as value, p.path,
(SELECT * FROM cascade_publish.folder
where path like 'csusm/history/%' and path not like 'csusm/history/%/%' )
from metadata_custom meta
right join page as p on p.id = meta.page_id
inner join metadata m on p.metadata_id = m.id
where p.path like 'csusm/history/%' and p.path not like 'csusm/history/%/%'
group by p.id

Comment: But I get an error code telling me the operand should only contain 1 column

Comment: Because you're using `select *` in the subquery, you can only select a single field. My example shows `SELECT folder FROM cascade_publish` - it's selecting a single col

Comment: Ok, I see... When I try selecting with just one field in that subquery I get an error because the subquery returns more than one row... So should I even be using a subquery? Because I do want that second query to return several rows.

Comment: Correct - if possible you can use another join but if that's not possible you'll need the separate query.

Answer (score 0):

You can put a `SELECT` with an alias anywhere that a table would normally go. For example:

```
SELECT * FROM table
JOIN (SELECT * FROM other_table WHERE x = 10) AS temp
```

or, like this:

```
SELECT SUM(temp.value) FROM (SELECT MAX(value) AS value FROM my_table GROUP BY whatever) AS temp
```